# Populate mysqldump data into a table: only for rows which exist in a given database

Tags: mysql

1. Old database with out inforation
2. Refactored database with a number of removed columns

I'd like to dump the old database, and repopulate the new DB.

... But only if the new database has a given column

Example:

- old_DB User table has 5 columns : Login, Email, City, State, Phone
- new_DB User table has  columns : Login, Email, Phone

Is there a mass operation which I can run to ONLY populate Login, Email and Phone only ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the two DBs are running within the same mysql instance, you can do

```
INSERT INTO newdb.newtable (field1, field2, ....)
    SELECT FROM olddb.oldtable (field1, field2, ...)
```

as a single query. No need to use a dump. Relevant docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: SO I've checked this out ... and sadly its a step LESS automated than would be IDEAL... is there a way to return the fields present in newdb.newtable and use that to populate the SELECT FROM statement?

Comment: also I've tried a few variants ... and they don't seem to work https://gist.github.com/delinquentme/5209367  and for the record I'm trying to insert all the rows ... not one at a time :D

Comment: you can query information_schema to get field names, and use that info to build the query. but generally, why don't you just dump/import the ENTIRE database then alter/drop the unwanted fields afterwards? sometimes it's easier that way than trying to keep a field or two from being exported to begin with.

Comment: Noted. Now what about how to structure the statements listed in that GIST?

Comment: Also it looks like the fields should be between SELECT and FROM .. right?

Answer (score 0):

So a modified working version of Marc B's statement is here:

```
INSERT INTO asdf_mock.citations_sites (`citation_id`, `site_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
   SELECT `citation_id`, `site_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` 
   FROM asdf_production.citations_sites;
```

Running this with the back-tick quotes gives the desired insertion.